# Euler's Continued Fraction Formula -- Some Reading?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, continued-fractions

Can anyone direct me to some reading on Generalised Continued Fractions and the proof of Euler's Continued Fraction Formula?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @ Hugh Entwistle: Perhaps this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746098/how-to-use-eulers-continued-fraction-formula/1746793#1746793) may be useful