# Convert $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ to continued fraction

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I want to convert $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ to continued fraction. I want to use the theorem that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\alpha_{k}} = \frac{1}{\alpha_{1}}_{+} \frac{\alpha_{1}^{2}}{\alpha_{2} - \alpha_{1}}_{+} \frac{\alpha_{2}^{2}}{\alpha_{3} - \alpha_{2}}_{+}\frac{\alpha_{3}^{2}}{\alpha_{4} - \alpha_{3}}_{+}\ldots $$But this needs an alternating series. However, I'm confused about how to express $\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$ as an alternating series. 
 And my eventual goal is to get the continued fraction for $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$, which I think i could get from the continued fraction for $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Comment: You might be motivated by this often duplicated fact, [the sum of inverse squares equalis $\pi^2/6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954692/why-does-the-sum-of-inverse-squares-equal-pi2-6).  We can shoehorn that into your scheme by replacing $\alpha_k$ by $-\alpha_k$ for *odd* indexes $k$.  Of course the scheme was never designed to give *simple* continued fractions (as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Basic_formula)).

Comment: @hardmath This is really helpful.

Comment: The power of $-1$ in your alternating series seems to be off-by-one.  Compare [this previous Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1746793/3111) which has $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{a_{n}}$$/

Comment: @hardmath Yeah you're right